# How many isomorphisms are there from $\Bbb Z_{12}$ to $\Bbb Z_{4} \oplus \Bbb Z_{3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many isomorphisms are there from $\Bbb Z_{12}$ to $\Bbb Z_{4} \oplus \Bbb Z_{3}$?

I can see that if $f$ is the isomorphism, the isomorphism is determined by the value of $f(1)$ because $f(1) = (1,1)$ and $f(k) = f(k) + f(1) = f(k) + (1,1)$.  But since $\Bbb Z_{12}$ has $4$ generators, there are $4$ different ways to set $f(1)$ equal to a generator.  Therefore there are $4$ isomorphisms.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, sounds good

Comment: But not necessarily $f(1)=(1,1)$. (Or wait, is $1$ the *neutral* element in your notation?)

Comment: So $f(1)$ can equal any of the generators that still creates the isomorphism?  $1$ is the natural number $1$.

Comment: I think you meant to write $f(k) = kf(1) = k(1,1) = (k,k)$.

Comment: What Bernard describes works generally of course. If $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic then the number of isomorphisms $A\to B$ is the number of automorphisms of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\;\pi \colon\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z \to\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ be the canonical isomorphism. If $f$ is any isomorphism, it induces an automorphism $\;f\circ\pi^{-1}\colon\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z\to \mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$, and this correspondence is  bijective.

Thus there are as many isomorphisms from $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z\;$ to $\;\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ as automorphisms of $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$.

Suuch an automorphism is defined by the image of  $1$, which must be another generator, i.e. a unit mod. $12$. There are $\varphi(12)=\varphi(3)\cdot\varphi(4)=2\cdot 2=4\;$ generators.

Comment: What's a canonical isomorphism?  I haven't come across that term in my book.

Comment: It's  the natural isomorphism $\;n+ 12\mathbf Z\mapsto (n+3\mathbf Z,n+4\mathbf Z)$.